# Delete ID and delete with another ID

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I want to delete customer id where id customer in table order is doesn't exist

```
DELETE FROM 
    customers a 
WHERE 
    a.id_customers IN(
        SELECT 
            c.id_customers 
        FROM 
            customers c 
        WHERE 
            c.id_customers NOT IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                    o.customer_id 
                FROM orders o
            )
    )
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'a WHERE a.id_customers IN(SELECT c.id_customers FROM customers c WHERE c.id_cust' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as without aliasing **a** as in the following query

```
DELETE FROM customers 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        ( SELECT 0
            FROM orders o 
           WHERE customers.id_customers = o.customer_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
DELETE customers a WHERE a.id_customers NOT IN (SELECT id_customers FROM orders GROUP BY id_customers) b
```